# Catching exceptions that don't inherit from Exception

Tags: python, exception

I have a database access module that I call with a query or a command. It figures out what to do with the database, and tries to do it. But, for instance if the query or command string is pathological, the call to the underlying PGDB module can throw an exception.

Some incredibly useful information is returned by PGDB (from PostgreSQL under that), specifically calling out what errors were found in the query or command. This kind of usage of PGDB's various functions retrieves that information:

```
try:
    pgdb.dothing(mod.withx)
except Exception, e:
    mod.error = 'pgdb.dothing('+str(type(mod.withx))+str(mod.withx)+') failed with: '+str(e)
```

Then when the class returns, having failed, the object contains the message in .error and viola, I can fix my stupidity in the query or command.

And this all seems to work just fine -- (in Python 2.2.2, which might change to 2.higher someday... but not now -- and never, ever to 3.whatever)

But... I have found this bit of opacity: "**exception doesn't have to be inherited from Exception. Thus plain 'except:' catches all exceptions, not only system. String exceptions are one example of an exception that doesn't inherit from Exception**"

So here's the question: Why do I care? If an exception is thrown, I want to know why. I don't care where it came from, really, I just want the error message, and I sure don't want Python to come to a crashing halt. That would include if the error came from the string thing or whatever. So except catching everything is good. Or it should be.

Is it that the parameter of Exception means, I won't catch an error if it comes from, for instance, the String innards? And that then, the code will halt with an uncaught exception? And that then I'd need a series of catches for every type that "doesn't inherit from exception" in order to get the behavior I want? Something like this:

```
try:
    pgdb.dothing(mod.withx)
except Exception, e:
    mod.error = 'pgdb.dothing('+str(type(mod.withx))+str(mod.withx)+') failed with: '+str(e)
except:
    mod.error = 'pgdb.dothing('+str(type(mod.withx))+str(mod.withx)+') failed with: WTF???'
```

...because that really... kinda sucks.

And, if that's the case, is there some other way I can catch all exceptions of all types and grab the error message for them? It seems like this would be something that is highly, highly desirable (and it also seems like a one-liner should solve it, and it should look somewhat like the former example, rather than the latter.)

Please, before you answer: Yes, I know Python 2.2.2 is old. No, it's not going to be upgraded soon. This is a production system with several million lines of code; it's stable and we want it to remain that way, based upon, "not broken, not fixing."

I just need a solid understanding of this part of the exception process beaten into me. All the explanations seem to be making assumptions about what I know that are... optimistic. :)

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, although this is a bad practice. You should be as explicit as possible when overriding errors.

```
try:
    ...
except:
    e = sys.exc_info()
    print e
```

I also suggest taking a look at https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions

Comment: "I also suggest taking a look at..." I did. That's where I got the quote about except not always being from Exception from. Looks like your answer, above, does what I'm asking about. Thank you very much. Also, I'm not overriding errors. I'm trying to find out what the error WAS, and since I'm not there when it happens, generally speaking, I need to capture this and get it to myself -- and the user, at least in some form.

Comment: @fyngyrz, Not a problem. No offence intended, either, I just like linking to documentation with my answers. If my answer helped you, why not consider hitting the check mark on the left? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Wow. It's going to take a bit of time to unpack some of the wrong assumptions in this question.

Catching everything is not at all desirable. How can it be? If an exception is raised, that's because something has gone wrong. You can't possibly write code that deals with every error that could ever happen, simply because no code is perfect. So exceptions are raised when unforeseen errors happen, and you write handling code for the ones you know you can handle.

But that still leaves things you can't handle: why would you want to catch those? What would you do, having caught them? There's no point saying "I'll just log them, and carry on", because now your system is in an undefined state. Does that piece of data exist? Don't know. Has it been written to the db? Can't tell. Have you just lost millions in revenue? Search me, guv.

As regards the Python version, if the fact that you are running a production system on an unsupported platform on which a large number of serious vulnerabilities have not only been discovered but actually exploited does not count as "broken", then I don't know what does.

Comment: The point in catching them is so that the upper levels can pass that error along to the user, who is staring at a web browser, and will not be in the least enlightened by a message from the web browser that the CGI went nipples north, and notify IT. I can at *least* say "DB operation failed", so your session is closed. The IT department has been notified." Your assumption that "catch" = "carry on regardless" is bogus. Regarding your assumption of vulnerabilities, these systems are not on the WAN. It would have been great if you actually answered the question instead of calling snark(MAX)

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. It's a comment, albeit an elaborate one.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `sys.exc_info()` to get the exception information in your plain `execpt:` clause.

Comment: Thank you. That's part of it, all right, but sys.exc_info() returns (,,) for a query formatting error, whereas Exception,e returns the specific screwup. so it's both: except: Exception,e: followed by except: and capture from sys.exc_info()

Comment: You are certainly right about the longer answer being much better than mine.  But you are wrong about what `sys.exc_info()` returns.  A value like `(,,)` does not exist in Python.  It should be the correct value triple (exception type, exception instance, traceback).  If you get an output of `(,,)` this is probably due to some unusual frontend you are using.

Comment: Interesting. The only front end I am aware of is PGDB. When I catch Exception,e: I get the expected values. When I catch except: only, then e=sys.exc_info(), what I get prints out as "(,,)" It may be an artifact of early python or something, too. I'll cook up some test cases, it's easy enough to do. Next comment soon.

Comment: ok, that was weird. Got exactly the results you described. No empty looking tuple-like thing. I even provoked the error the same way (changed a column name in a query to a non-existent column), just removed the Exception,e: catch in a test copy of the db utes module so it would fall into the sys. mechanism. Well, you're clearly right and I'm clearly wrong, but I did see what I described. I'll have to think about this. Must have done something really wrong somewhere. It's certainly possible. Thanks for the clarity. An "up" for you. :)